# What if a condition variable signals to a locked thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

In the (pseudo-)code below, `cond` might wake up while it shouldn't, for whatever reason. So I put a while loop there. When it does wake up, it will still consume the lock, so it is guaranteed that in `out()` only one thread is doing its job.

But what happens if, while there is a spurious wake-up in `out()`, at the same time `in()` signals to `out()`, however at that very moment `out()` is already locked because of the spurious wake-up. So what happens if the `cond` signals to a locked thread?

```
in()
    inLock.lock()
    isEmpty = false
    cond.signal()
    inLock.unlock()

out()
    outLock.lock()
    while isEmpty
        cond.wait(outLock)
    isEmpty = true
    outLock.unlock()
```

NOTE

Well, to be 100% safe, I know I can use a single mutex for both `in()` and `out()`, but the data structure I'm using is 100% safe when input and output happens at the same time; it is a type of a queue. And I think it is a performance compromise to block anything reading out from the queue while filling in some new data or vice versa.

I did consider using semaphores, but the problems is that so many C and C++ libraries don't implement semaphores for whatever reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the same mutex when the `in()` thread sets `isEmpty = false` and the `out()` thread tests `while (isEmpty)`.  Otherwise, this can happen:

1. `out()` thread tests `isEmpty`, finds it is true;
2. `in()` thread sets `isEmpty` to false and signals the condition variable (but no-one wakes up, beacuse no-one is waiting yet);
3. `out()` thread calls `cond.wait()` and blocks forever, despite the fact that the queue is not empty anymore.

Note that in this sequence there hasn't been a spurious wakeup - it's just a plain old race condition.

As long as you update `isEmpty` with the same mutex held as when you test `isEmpty`, this interleaving can't happen.

Answer (score 2):

> So what happens if the cond signals to a locked thread?

The signal is lost forever. If no threads are waiting for the signal when `pthread_cond_signal` is called, then `pthread_cond_signal` does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Since `isEmpty` is being read and modified by two different threads, it is an error to access it unprotected. This is essentially what you are doing when you allow `in` and `out` to use different lock instances.

Using different lock instances on the same condition variable is a violation of the [POSIX API for `pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) (emphasis mine).

> **The effect of using more than one mutex for concurrent `pthread_cond_wait()`** or `pthread_cond_timedwait()` **operations on the same condition variable is undefined**; that is, a condition variable becomes bound to a unique mutex when a thread waits on the condition variable, and this (dynamic) binding ends when the wait returns.